# Gvim: Ubuntu letter spacing (Consolas font)

Tags: vim

Thought I could just copy my vimrc from my Windows to my Linux box but running into a few problems with the letter spacing on Ubuntu.

[image: Vim preview]

Hope this is the right place to ask this question with all these new stackexachange sites.

**Update:**

The font is correctly installed I think. From the menu I can select it and it works fine.

[image: Ubuntu font directory]

Comment: If you don't get a satisfactory answer here, superuser.com (another Stack Exchange site) can probably help.

Comment: Try removing the :h11 and see what happens. I find I have to play around with the font width and height settings even when I move from on UNIX to another. The easiest is not to specify anything and let GVIM decide.

Comment: Ah, I forgot to mention that without the h11 the spacing is fine but the font is to small to work with. Also in gvim if I set the font from the menu and change the size it's also okay.

Comment: Are you sure you have that specific font in Ubuntu? It might be substituting with another one.

Comment: Updated my question to show the font in the fonts directory.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

AFAIK the `:h` thing only works on Windows and OS X, in Linux it should be

```
:set guifont=Consolas\ 11
```

The weird display is usually caused by wrong font setting.
If you are using gvim in different OSs, you can put this to your `.gvimrc`:

```
if has("gui_gtk2")
    set guifont=Consolas\ 11
elseif has("gui_macvim")
    set guifont=Consolas:h12
elseif has("gui_win32")
    set guifont=Consolas:h11
end
```

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/3531/how-to-save-font-choice-in-gvim You need to make sure you escape the font size like in the example here. I missed that! Thanks for the useful answer.

Comment: This could also mean that the font doesn't exist.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know what the `:h` directive is supposed to do, but

```
:set guifont=Consolas:h11
```

yields horrible intraletter spacing, but

```
:set guifont=Consolas\ 11
```

is fine. (But `set guifont=Droid\ Sans\ Mono` is better still ;)

Comment: The `:h` is for Mac and Windows.

Comment: @msw, +1 I also like the Droid Sans Mono better than Consolas