# Why doesn't the font setting work in gvim?

Tags: vim, fonts

In Fedora15, I was originally using **vim**, with all my settings defined in my `~/.vimrc` file. I recently installed vim-X11, and have now transitioned to **gvim**. I defined a `~/.gvimrc` file, with the following line to set the font:

```
set guifont=Bitstream_Vera_Sans_Mono:h11:cANSI
```

However, it doesn't work. There are two strange things:

1. The other settings such as line number, color scheme works right, but font setting doesn't work. Instead, I need to set them in the tool bar every time to change the font: "Edit->Select Font".
2. Every time I select "Edit -> Startup Settings", it opens the `~/.vimrc` file instead of the `~/.gvimrc` file.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your `guifont` is valid only on Windows. In GTK GVim, you want:

```
set guifont=Bitstream\ Vera\ Sans\ Mono\ 11
```

Also, you can use `set guifont=*` to bring up a system dialog to choose a font, and then look at the contents of the setting with `set guifont?`.

GVim loads `.vimrc` and then `.gvimrc`, so you can separate settings that apply only to GUI version.

Comment: Thank you very much. If there is a setting, the key in ~/.gvimrc is the the same as in ~/.vimrc, but the value is different, the ~/.gvimrc's value will override ~/.vimrc's value, is it right?

Comment: @TankyWoo: Yes, `.gvimrc` is always loaded after `.vimrc`. See `:help gvimrc`.

Comment: :Thank you for helping me solve this question so fast and perfect. Tanky you.

Answer (score 0):

I find use `set guifont=*` then `set guifont?` will not  work， but`set guifont=Bitstream\ Vera\ Sans\ Mono\ 11` nice

Comment: if want know more about gvim font ,click [`more detail answer`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539437/gvim-ubuntu-letter-spacing-consolas-font)