# Can letter spacing be set somehow in gVim Editor

Tags: vim, text-formatting, letter-spacing

I've discovered many sources which have said it cannot be tightened up and that the space between letters within a word is not something the user can adjust.  At first I didn't believe it, but after applying a few *tips* such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539437) and having the editor continue to display text with the letters evenly spaced, I wonder.

Has anyone experienced or come across a way to set letter spacing?

Comment: The letter spacing is dependent on your font, as in the question linked to.

Comment: Some terminal emulators like iTerm on Mac OS X allow you to do that but you'll probably ned to dive into GVim's source if you want such a feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vim (out of necessity, because it runs in the terminal) and GVIM (for consistency) use a cell-based addressing scheme, so they require a fixed-size matrix of screen cells. On Windows GVIM, you even can only use fonts that are fixed-width.

Therefore, the only way to influence the perceived spacing between letters is through the selected font (and its size). If you feel that the letters are too far apart, you need to either edit the font (to reduce the width of all characters), or choose another one.

GVIM does allow to tweak the vertical padding between screen lines through the `'linespace'` option, though.

Comment: I liked linespace-2 with consolas, only it left little pieces of text all over the screen when I scrolled.  Not sure if this is a gvim or a device driver issue!